# I want to remove vowels in a string in scheme, but I cannot get to the last step

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (devowel str)
  (list->string (devowel/list (string->list str))))
(define (devowel/list str)
  (cond
    [(empty? str) empty]
    [(empty? (rest str)) empty]
    [(string? (first str) "a" "e" "I" "o" "u") (devowel (rest str))]
    [else (cons (first str)(devowel/list (rest str)))]))
(devowel "apple")
```

I try to remove vowels in a string, but I stuck at (string? (first str) "a" "e" "I" "o" "u") and is gives an error said string?: expects only 1 argument, but found 2
the only function I am allowed to use is (list->string)(string->list)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to rename `str` argument in `(define (devowel/list str) ...)`, because you are passing list of characters, not string. You have already used `str` in `(define (devowel str) ...` and it seems that both functions accept some string, which is not true. In my code below, I will use `lst`.

Next, remove this clause `[(empty? (rest str)) empty]`, because your function always removes last character in list.

```
(devowel "racket") => "rck"
```

Also this clause `[(string? (first str) "a" "e" "I" "o" "u") (devowel (rest str))]` is wrong.

Function [`string?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._string%7E3f%29%29) expects one argument and checks whether it's string or not:

```
> (string? "hello")
#true
> (string? 5)
#false
```

You are calling this function with six arguments: `(string? (first str) "a" "e" "I" "o" "u")` and that causes the error.

You will actually need another function:

1. You can use `eq?` and `or` and create clause like this:

```
[(or (eq? (first lst) #\a)
     (eq? (first lst) #\e)
     (eq? (first lst) #\i)
     (eq? (first lst) #\o)
     (eq? (first lst) #\u)
     (eq? (first lst) #\y))
 (devowel/list (rest lst))]
```

(Note that I replaced `devowel` with `devowel/list`.) This can be enough, but it's very long, repetetive and if you decide to check uppercase vowels as well, you will have to add six more lines.

2. Use built-in function `member` or write your own `member`:

```
 [(member (first lst) (list #\a #\e #\i #\o #\u #\y))
     (devowel/list (rest lst))]
```

(Here is possible implementation of `member`:

```
(define (my-member v lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) #false)
        ((eq? v (first lst)) #true)
        (else (my-member v (rest lst)))))
```

)

3. Some other ways include using `filter` or regular expressions:

```
(define (devowel2 str)
  (list->string (filter (lambda (c) (not (member c (list #\a #\e #\i #\o #\u #\y))))
                        (string->list str))))

(define (devowel3 str)
  (regexp-replace* #rx"[aeiouy]" str ""))
```

So, your function with all suggested changes can look like this:

```
(define (devowel str)
  (list->string (devowel/list (string->list str))))

(define (devowel/list lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [(member (first lst) (list #\a #\e #\i #\o #\u #\y))
     (devowel/list (rest lst))]
    [else (cons (first lst)(devowel/list (rest lst)))]))

(devowel "racket")
(devowel "apple")
```